# C# Stuck with a parsing error while trying to make a random number generator

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a 'guess the number' game for a task in uni and I'm stuck on (what I think) is a parsing issue.

It doesn't show up any errors before I run the program but when it gets to a certain point (after clicking the message box it quits and throws up possible errors and solutions).

I did want to try and fix this myself and I did search everywhere for this but it's not giving me an exact error so I'm a bit stuck on what to search for.

I've included the code below and a link to the screenshot of the error.

Many thanks, Rob

screen shot link : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlWo6.jpg)

```cs
 private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Random gen = new Random();
     int randNumber = gen.Next(1, 1000);
     lblWelcome.Text = ("");
     btnGenerate.Visible = false;

     MessageBox.Show("The computer has picked a number and stored it, please continue and guess the number");

     txtbxInputNumber.Visible = true;
     int guess = int.Parse(txtbxInputNumber.Text);

     while (guess != randNumber)
     {
        if (guess < randNumber)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Try higher");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Try lower");
        }
     }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: The value you're trying to parse when you get the exception is `""`, or an empty string. This is not a correct integer format indeed.

Comment: Your code gets stuck in thw while  loop because you never update `guess`

Comment: Look to use TryParse to handly this nicely.

Comment: Did using TryParse helped you, like I suggest in my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You should `TryParse` your input from the user, not always this can be valid number

```
int guess = 0;
int.TryParse(txtbxInputNumber.Text, out guess);
```

You can show an error if you want so he knows that he made an mistake

```
int guess = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(txtbxInputNumber.Text, out guess))
{
    //show error message
    return; // quit the method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I look at the screenshot, your `txtbxInputNumber.Text` is empty! Thats not a valid Int.

You should use, `int.TryParse()`

```
int guess;

if(int.TryParse(txtbxInputNumber.Text, out guess))
{
    // the guess is a valid int!
}
else
{
    // the guess is not a valid int!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the input string being blank, the parse does not recognise it as a number, you should add a condition

```
int guess = int.Parse(txtbxInputNumber.Text == "" ? "0" : txtbxInputNumber.Text);
```

This is the same as using an if, though an if statement has the bonus that you can return an error

```
if(txtbxInputNumber.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Try higher");
    return;
}
else
{
    int guess = int.Parse(txtbxInputNumber.Text);
}
```

You could also restrict the input to number so that it will automatically have a number in it

The other option is to use a TryParse, in which case guess must be instantiated first as it is required as an out parameter

Comment: What if `txtbxInputNumber.Text` contains `A`?

Comment: That's where the number restriction comes into play, and also the suggsetion of a tryparse

Answer (score 0):

It throws an exception because the input is not a number. Use [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Int32.Parse`.

```
int guess;
if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbxInputNumber.Text, out guess))
     MessageBox.Show("Enter a number");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the txtInputBox value is null when you try to enter the loop.  Place the inputbox line inside the while loop and add a check for not null.  Should work then something like this:

```
    int guess = 0;
    while (guess != randNumber)
    {
        if !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbxInputNumber.Text)
        { 
           guess = int.Parse(txtbxInputNumber.Text);
           if (guess < randNumber)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Try higher");
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Try lower");
           }
        }
    }
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'int.Parse' try with 'int.TryParse'.

```
  int guess ;
  //int guess = int.Parse(txtbxInputNumber.Text); //Instead of this
  int.TryParse(txtbxInputNumber.Text, out guess ); //use this
```